# Compile cpp files in TMB: error: ld returned 5 exit status

Tags: c++, r, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a C++ source file with "TMB::compile" function in R, but the compilation fails giving following messages:

```
> library(TMB) 
> compile("hmm_simple.cpp")
using C++ compiler: ‘G__~1.EXE (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o hmm_simple.dll tmp.def hmm_simple.o -LC:/RBuildTools/4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/RBuildTools/4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
```

The environment setup is:

- R version 4.3.1
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Rtools 42
- OS: Windows 11

Note:

- The cpp file that I am trying to compile has been previously compiled on the Linux system, which works out fine in giving .o and .so files. So I guess the file itself is good. Now I want to use it on the Windows 11 system,but the compilation crashes.
- You can find the "hmm_simple.cpp" through [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGB__DiIIrldW1vFc6NXUOTHLC5OIPzJ/view?usp=share_link). It would be great that you help compile this cpp file in your set-up and share your results with me:)

Thank you for helping!

I have tried：

- Replace "RBuildTools" with "rtools42" for compiling C++ files. "rtools42" worked out fine based on my test, but from the error message it seems that the cpp file is still compiled with "RBuildTools". I don't know why this happens and whether this is the cause for final error.

I am expecting:

- Compile "hmm_simple.cpp" using the "TMB::compile" in R, giving the .dll file for further application of the package.